# Object in Rendered Mode is different from Material Preview Mode

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

So I'm making a running train in Geometry Node but the object looks different when switching between Material Preview & Rendered View.

[image: Here is Rendered View]

[image: Here is Material Preview View]

This is my node setup
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to flip some normals :

In *Edit Mode* select *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*